# Fill div with dynamically overflow

Tags: css

I am trying to scroll div element with class o-body and fit space between o-header and o-footer. But the element with class o-footer has dynamically height, the height depends on number of elements in buttons collection.
How make element with class o-body scrollable and its height changed based on height of element with class o-footer.
Sorry my english.

```css
.o-container {
  position: relative;
   height: 200px;
}

.o-header {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.o-body { 
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
}

.o-footer {     
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="o-container">
  <div class="o-header">
   <div>
    headerrow1
    </div>
    <div>
    headerrow2
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="o-body">
    <div>
    bodyrow1
    </div>
    <div>
    bodyrow2
    </div>
    <div>
    bodyrow3
    </div>
    <div>
    bodyrow4
    </div>
    <div>
    bodyrow5
    </div>
     <div>
    bodyrow6
    </div>
    <div>
    bodyrow7
    </div>
    <div>
    bodyrow8
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="o-footer">
  <div data-bind="foreach: buttons">    
   <div>
    footerrow1
    </div>
    <div>
    footerrow2
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't use external code references. Instead, use a Stack snippet: Click "Edit" below your question, then the button that resembles `<>`.

Comment: Can you try to explain a bit more what you are trying to do? I'm not 100% sure based on your explanation.

Comment: Its one page. One div as header, one div as body and one div as footer. The header has static height. But the height of footer is not static, the height depends on its changeble content. I want the content in body div scrollable and its height fit between header and footer.

Comment: It seems like your current code already meets those requirements?

Comment: No. When in footer will be more content, then the footer will be over the div body.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of `position: relative/absolute` is a bit off putting as it inhibits a proper solution to your problem.

Containers `.o-container` and `.o-footer` need to be able to grow, where `.o-header` and `.o-body` containers do not.

There is no plain CSS way to resize container `.o-body` based on the number of buttons inside `.o-footer`. You cannot simply say something like `.o-body { height: calc((.o-footer.child-count - 2) * 1rem)`. You will need Javascript for that.

We can simplify things somewhat by using *CSS custom properties*. I introduced CSS variable `--rows` which has to be changed to the required number of rows when a button gets added to `.o-footer`. This way both `.o-body` and `.o-footer` can grow without overlapping.

The simple JS for `--rows` is `document.body.style.setProperty('--rows', requiredRows);`

In below snippet I removed all the `position: relative/absolute` references and created a (commented) base structure you can use. Including easy access to some generic document line-height (`--lh`) and padding (`--pd`) CSS variables.

No JS as I don't know how the buttons get added to `.o-footer`...

**Snippet**

```css
body {
    --lh  : 1.5;    /* document default line height */
    --pd  : 0.5rem; /* some default padding (inner spacing) */
    --rows: 7;      /* # of rows visible in .o-body */

    line-height: var(--lh);
}

.o-container {
    display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap;
    padding: var(--pd);

    width: 8rem; /* some width you require */
 }

.o-container .o-header { padding-bottom: var(--pd) }
.o-container .o-footer { padding-top   : var(--pd) }

.o-body {
    overflow-y: auto;

    /* calculate height relative to lh and rows in REM */
    height: calc(var(--lh) * var(--rows) * 1rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="o-container">
    <div class="o-header">
        <div>header row1</div>
        <div>header row2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="o-body">
        <div>body row1</div>
        <div>body row2</div>
        <div>body row3</div>
        <div>body row4</div>
        <div>body row5</div>
        <div>body row6</div>
        <div>body row7</div>
        <div>body row8</div>
        <div>body row9</div>
        <div>body row10</div>
        <div>body row11</div>
        <div>body row12</div>
        <div>body row13</div>
    </div>

    <div class="o-footer">
        <div data-bind="foreach: buttons">
            <div>footer row1</div>
            <div>footer row2</div>
            <div>footer row3</div>
            <div>footer row4</div>
            <div>footer row5</div>
            <div>footer row6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? I have added comments in the code to make it more clear, hope this help!

```css
.o-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.o-header {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.o-body { 
  position: relative; /* change this from absolute to relative */
  /* overflow-y: scroll; */
  height: auto; /* change the height to be auto */
}

.o-footer {     
  position: relative; /* change this from absolute to relative */
  /* bottom: 0px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="o-container">
  <div class="o-header">
   <div>
    headerrow1
    </div>
    <div>
    headerrow2
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="o-body">
    <div>
    bodyrow1
    </div>
    <div>
    bodyrow2
    </div>
    <div>
    bodyrow3
    </div>
    <div>
    bodyrow4
    </div>
    <div>
    bodyrow5
    </div>
     <div>
    bodyrow6
    </div>
    <div>
    bodyrow7
    </div>
    <div>
    bodyrow8
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="o-footer">
  <div data-bind="foreach: buttons">    
   <div>
    footerrow1
    </div>
    <div>
    footerrow2
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```